# push strings to an object using JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(resultParsed)) {
    if(this.partialParams.includes(key.toUpperCase())){
     let a= ((`"${key}": "${value}"`))

        console.log(a);
    }
}
```

it outputs

```
"a":"8" 
"b":"10"
```

i need this to be wrapped like this `{"a":"8","b":"10"}`

Comment: Make it ```let a= {[key]: value}```

Comment: Why not just `JSON.stringify(resultParsed)`?

Comment: makes it two objects-NOT GOOD. has to be one object

Comment: stringify will get all the keys and values- NOT GOOD

Comment: @eladbasat - Just FWIW, putting "NOT GOOD" in all caps can easily come off as rude to the person reading it, who was trying to help you.

Comment: Are you trying to create an *object* or a *string*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define the final output as an object outside the for loop scope, and add the output object property if the search scenario is passed.

```
var output = {};
for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(resultParsed)) {
    if(this.partialParams.includes(key.toUpperCase())){
        output[key] = value;
    }
}

if (Object.keys(output).length)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

Comment: @eladbasat you must refer the answer of T.J. Crowder answer too he added broad descriptive solution

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me whether you want to create an *object* or a string.

#### An object

Assuming you want to create an object: Create the object, then add the properties to it. There are a couple of ways to do that. With a loop as you have now, just adjusted a bit:

```
const a = {}; // *** Create the object
for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(resultParsed)) {
    if(this.partialParams.includes(key.toUpperCase())){
        a[key] = value; // *** Add the property
    }
}
console.log(a);
```

...but instead since you're using `Object.entries`, which creates the kind of input `Object.fromEntries` wants, you could use `filter` instead:

```
const a = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(resultParsed).filter(([key, value]) => this.partialParams.includes(key.toUpperCase()))
);
console.log(a);
```

#### A string

If you want to create a *string*, do the above and use `JSON.stringify` on the result.

Or if you prefer not to, you can also build the string via `join`:

```
const a =
    "{" +
    Object.entries(resultParsed)
        .filter(([key, value]) =>
            this.partialParams.includes(key.toUpperCase())
        )
        .map(([key, value]) =>
            `${JSON.stringify(key)}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`
        )
        .join(", ") +
    "}";
console.log(a);
```

...but I think you're better off just building the object and using `JSON.stringify` on it.